# Trying to colate click fraud evidence

Tags: log-files, filtering

We've recently had some very heavy and unexpected Google adwords spikes recently, so I'm trying to work through the server logs to find out if we've been subject to click fraud.

What I don't know is what I'm looking for.

I know the dates, but not what I'm actually looking for in the logs.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is and isn't on-topic here -- log analysis is certainly something we do, but where the answers wound up (inside Google's tools) isn't really a fit for Server Fault.  If the Google tools didn't get you what you needed let me know and I'll help you rework this into a log analysis question & reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to utilize your web analytics tools for this purpose.

You should probably start with a visit to the [Google Ads Ad Traffic Quality Resource Center](http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/ads/adtrafficquality/index.html).

[Here](http://adwords.blogspot.com/2007/02/meet-click-quality-team.html) is an InsideAdWords blog post with good information on the topic.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking into that now.  I can see an unexpected doubling of paid traffic coming to our website, but we can't account for this.  On first glance this looks okay because is comes from our territory, the UK but it needs more analysis.

Comment: Actually, the above link is very useful as it contains the page for raising a click investigation request.  This I think will resolve my issue so I'm setting it as the answer.